# Can a question get an accepted answer if OP doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: discussion, deleted-users

I found a few questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856707/sql-insert-into-values-select), where the OP doesn't exist anymore, but the question is still not answered. I understand that nothing like "community accepting" the question is acceptable if the OP exists and there is a chance that he'll accept the answer - but how about these questions?
What can/should be done with them? And possibly, if some statistics are available - how many questions without an accepted answer and without existing OP are on SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these cannot ever have an accepted answer (barring a dev manually changing the database). That's a big part of why answers are sorted by votes by default - the best answers as determined by the community float to the top.  As for statistics, you could probably pull it out of [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think the OP asks how the system *should* work and not how it *actually* works ATM.

Comment: actually sometimes an accepted answer have less votes than other answers but still be raised to top

Comment: Would this rule (that only the OP can mark as accepted) also apply for this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111747/how-to-install-apk-file-using-android-avd ? There's only one answer, no activity in over a year, and the OP hasn't been online in over a year, but that answer clearly solved his problem by the comments.

Comment: @TomHart Yes, in all cases the OP has to accept; if the OP is deleted (or unregistered and loses the cookie it's just impossible for that to happen. If there's still a user, it's possible for them to come back and accept.

Answer (score 2):

Acceptance isn't really a requirement for SO. Looking at the upvotes, you can already clearly see what the best answer is and since answers are ordered by votes by default, you get a good view of the better answers to the question. There is no need for it to be accepted.

As for the statistics: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/185628/239820/not-accepted-answers (46676 atm)

Comment: The accept flag usually signals that the answer worked in practice. So though there's no strict *need* for it, it certainly has some *value*.